# Не удается безопасно подключится к этой странице

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-server, windows-server-2012

Всем привет!

Есть хост Windows Server 2019 с установленными службами `AD`, `DHCP`, `DNS` и тд.
Установил на него vmware workstation 15, установил виртуальную машину, также Windows Server 2019, ввёл в домен.

Используется `internet-explorer`, и есть некая проблема с доступом к одному из интернет ресурсов, на виртуальной машине `через раз` удаётся зайти на этот самый ресурс, получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через пару нажатий `F5` - зайти удаётся.

Я уже перепробовал всё что можно с настройками `TLS` и безопасностью на виртуальной машине.
Но ни чего не помогает. Пробовал другие браузеры, в них такой ошибки нет, заходит на ресурс без каких-либо проблем с любой попытки.

На самом хосте таких проблем вообще не наблюдается, ни в каком браузере, работает всё отлично.
Думаю, может быть проблема в `DNS` сервера, который на хосте?
Ведь на `ВМ` указан DNS сервер хоста. Но всё остальное работает.

Ещё заметил такую штуку, что на `ВМ` в `прыжках` к этому ресурсу почему то два раза одни и тот же адрес указан. На хосте такого не наблюдается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`IP-адрес`, который выделен на скрине выше - это адрес шлюза, указанный в моём роутере.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать? Где проверить? Что я ещё не настроил?

Большое спасибо.

Добавлю:
Изначально ошибка была такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я поставил галку тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И по началу ресурс работал, но стоит его открыть ещё раз, то всё, ошибка, которая указана в начале вопроса.

Comment: Попробуйте снизить порог для валидации длины с помощью команды ```certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512```. Затем Log off / Log on. Вернуть сможете на 1024, если не поможет. Можно поиграться с флагами с помощью этой же утилиты ```certutil -setreg chain\EnableWeakSignatureFlags 2```. Желательно бекап сделать ветки Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CertDllCreateCertificateChainEngine\Config\Default

Comment: Хотя это не совсем то

Comment: А настройках IE поддержку версий SSL/TLS включали?

Comment: да, и ветки соответствующие создавал в реестре, и полностью снизил безопасность до низкого уровня, добавил сайт в доверенные

Comment: Обновил вопрос. добавил информацию.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а что собой представляет тот сертификат на том локальном сайте, который вы пытаетесь открыть? Что у него за параметры?